# How to forward request from cloudfront to istio host

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, istio, relative-url, istio-gateway

I am facing some challenge to forward request from Cloudfront to istio. I have a service running with istio-gateway host configured as

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: <name>
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  gateways:
  - <gateway>
  hosts:
  - <host>
  http:
  - corsPolicy:
      allowCredentials: true
      allowHeaders:
     .........
     ..........
```

I also have Cloudfront being configured for my UI. I want to make an URL relative to my UI so, I have configured some behavior as `/login` which I want to forward to this above host. However, it is not able to forward the request.
Notes:

1. I tried matching the TLS protocol both side
2. matched ACM certificate entry as well
   but still getting 404 on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more details about cloudfront and k8s ingress, I don't think the problem is the vs file, the 404 looks like alb disable cloudfront access.

Comment: Thanks for the response, figured out, it was an issue with the certificate being used and domain being whitelisted.